# Build JavaFX program in Eclipse Neon with JDK9

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, java-9, java-platform-module-system

I have the latest Eclipse Neon milestone build together with the e(fx)clipse plugin and the additional JDK9 support installed and would now like to build a first JavaFX program with JDK9. Unfortunately all JavaFX modules are not on the class path. Can anybody tell me how I can add these modules so that I can build a JavaFX program with this configuration?

Comment: I usually use m2e and maven to manage the [dependencies](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin#prepared-for-java-9).

Comment: I'm guessing here... Did you create a `module-info.java` as explained in [SotmS](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/)? Does it include any JavaFX modules?

Comment: Yes, I did. I get the error message "javafx.base cannot be resolved to a module." there. (Same message for the other javafx modules too.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the ***javafx*** eclipse plugin:
 [Download & Install we get you started](https://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html)

This should fix your problem

---edit----

Right click your project.

Go to -> **Build Path -> Add Library**

Select the **JavaFX SDK**

Comment: I already said in my first sentence that I did install this plugin? It does not help.

Comment: Oh .. my bad didn't read that ^^. I edited my Answer maybe this will help you,

Comment: Then its a Problem with the JDK 9